# MS Access - How to close a form without saving any changes?

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I'm relatively new to access and havent worked much in VBA. Im currently designing a project database for users at our office to submit ideas to.

I have a submission form and a few of the fields are required. In the code, I have it looking like this:

```
If IsNull(SchoolName) Then
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MissingInfoForm"

Else
  AssignmentStatus = "Unassigned"
  LastEditedBy = apicGetUserName()
  DoCmd.Save
  MsgBox "Submission Accepted"
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

(I literally just threw this together. I normally just use macros when doing things, but I feel this issue will require use of VBA.)

The problem I'm facing is that when the user has failed to put anything into the field SchoolName, it will show the MissingInfoForm and revert back to the submission form but Access still saves and creates a new record with all blank fields (or partially completed, I need it to not save at all if the field SchoolName is blank). This is an issue because there is a hub form that lists all the entries and I cannot have a bunch of blank submissions there.

I tried making sure that the form's Close function doesnt save it but it continues to do so.

Ive looked quite a bit online for some help and I've found examples in the form of "A Better Mouse Trap" and the Me.Undo command, however I am unable to correctly implement these in the way I'd like.

Can someone lend me some assistance? Im a fairly big noob to this stuff and could use some guidance.. this project database is expected to be done by this Friday (2 days from now).

Comment: One method is to use a form that is not bound to the table and to manually input the entry into the table when desired.  You'd use a "CurrentDb.Execute" statement to run the SQL required to insert the record after checking for all the conditions you need met before inserting the record.

Comment: Another method is to use a "CurrentDb.Execute" statement to DELETE the record if it has problems.  Put this portion in the "If" part of your "If" statement.